# What happened to Graphics Package in ELM 0.18?

Tags: elm

I downloaded [this](https://github.com/davydog187/elm-pong/blob/master/elm-package.json) project from Github, and tried to run it using elm version 0.18.

The project is originally written in a prev elm version so I tried to make it run on my version.

The compiler said `I cannot find module 'Graphics.Collage'.`

So I entered to the package [page](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/2.0.1/Graphics-Collage) and saw that it was part of core's package, but when I hitted the link to go to the latest version I got to [a page where I could no longer understand what is going on.](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/Graphics-Collage). 
Where it is written:

```
 problem with parameter 'version': Must have format MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH (e.g. 1.0.2)
```

1. Could someone make sense out of this?
2. How can I import Graphics package in elm 0.18?
3. How can I find the solution for other packages that show the same error in their page?

Comment: Also, a lot of people get angry when you say "ELM" vs "Elm"... Kinda like saying "SASS" when it's "Sass".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Elm really has a problem with packages being moved out of core. Try installing `evancz/elm-graphics` instead.

Also re question 3: I usually go to http://package.elm-lang.org/ and search for the package name from there.

Comment: Note that once you have the `elm-graphics` package, you will need to change the imports from `Graphics.Collage`, etc to just `Collage`. You can take a look inside the `elm-graphics` package once it is installed to see more about the modules.

Answer (score 2):

Judging by code history, the last time the the project that you are trying to build successfully built was in December 2014 ( there is a more recent commit in 2016 with the comment "Start upgrading to elm 0.17" but that looks incomplete).  In December 2014, the latest version of Elm was 0.14 .

Now the latest version of Elm is 0.18.  Each release along the way (0.15, 0.16, 0.17, 0.18) has introduced changes.  Most of these are documented in the release notes : http://elm-lang.org/blog (scroll down past the "Articles" on that page).

The changes introduced in Elm 0.17 came with an upgrade plan : https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-platform/blob/master/upgrade-docs/0.17.md . This upgrade plan mentions that "The functionality of Graphics.* now lives in evancz/elm-graphics" ( as Andreas Hultgren already pointed out ).  Another helpful document is this : http://faq.elm-community.org/17.html which contains more details about Graphics.Collage .

The Graphics.Collage change is only one of many changes introduced along the way from Elm 0.14 to Elm 0.18 .  This modified clone of the project you were working with : https://github.com/dc25/elm-pong should compile and run under Elm 0.18 .